# BigQuery load to partitioned Table

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

hello i am pretty new with bigquery, i am about to load data into partitioned table let's say its named as table1_partitioned, this table also has column named timestamp which at first in table creation i set this column as partition,
so with this command i tried to load to bigquery

bq load --source_format=CSV data_analysis.table1_partitioned$20231002 gs://bucket_bqload/table1_partitioned_202310021337.csv

my question is what difference this command with this command

bq load --source_format=CSV data_analysis.table1_partitioned gs://bucket_bqload/table1_partitioned_202310021337.csv

because when i tried both, i do

bq head --max_rows=5 data_analysis.table1_partitioned$20231002

both return same value. does when i dont specify partition, bigquery already automatically infer to column which i already defined when table creation??

Comment: Mentioning the partition data is optioinal if it's the date of the current day. But could be very useful to add/override data in a partition at another date. Note that type of partition is ingestion date partitioning, and not field based partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, when you don't specify a partition when loading data into a partitioned table, BigQuery will automatically infer the partition value based on the partition column that you specified when you created the table.**

In your example, the two commands that you provided are equivalent, and both commands will load the data into the `table1_partitioned$20231002` partition of the `table1_partitioned` table.

You can specify a partition when loading data into a partitioned table if you want to load the data into a specific partition. However, you do not need to specify a partition if you are loading the data into a single partition.

I hope this is helpful!